# C# List files in current directory with matching regex pattern in an array

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have three text files in my directory:

```
login.txt
43.txt
100001.txt
```

I would like to keep an array of all filenames in the current directory which have a naming convention of any number (up to six digits in length) followed by ".txt" as the file name.

I have tried this:

```
            Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^[0-9]{1,6}$");
            string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt")
                     .Where(path => pattern.IsMatch(path)).ToArray();

            foreach (var myFile in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Filename:" + myFile);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

But it isnt finding my files at all.

What is the correct approach to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add the extension  -> ^[0-9]{1,6}.txt$ Or use Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) before matching

Comment: @ZanyBaka thanks for the suggestion, I have tried both @"^[0-9]{1,6}.txt$" and @"^[0-9]{1,6}\.txt$" and the result is the same, nothing gets printed unfortunately.

Comment: use @"^[0-9]{1,6}\.txt$" and .Where(path => pattern.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(path))).ToArray();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex  pattern = new Regex(@"^[0-9]{1,6}\.txt$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string path    = @"c:\Temp\1\";

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt")
    .Where(path => pattern.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(path))).ToArray();

foreach (var myFile in files)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Filename:" + myFile);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked thank you! Do you know how I can keep only the digits and remove all other information? Currently it is storing the full filepath and the extension, ideally I would keep only the digits. Thanks again

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zanybaka/bb9cb82dbdb238e65bac3af245512e1b